# Fastlane crashlytics_path via Carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, fastlane, carthage

Quick overview:
I have a private cocoapod which adds Fabric and Crashlytics via Carthage.

And I have a run script in the build phase:

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
Input files: $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Crashlytics.framework
Output files: $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/Crashlytics.framework
```

In my podspec I have:

```
s.script_phases = [
    {
        :name => 'Fabric Setup',
        :script => '"${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/Carthage/Build/iOS/Fabric.framework/run" {key} {secret}',
        :execution_position => :after_compile
    }
]
```

So far so good.

In my app project that pulls in this private cocoapod i'm using fastlane.

```
crashlytics(
    crashlytics_path: "...",
    api_token: "...",
    build_secret: "...",
    groups: "..."
)
```

I'm trying to work out what to put for the crashlytics_path so that it points to the Crashlytics.framework generated by my private cocoapod carthage.

Project folder structures:

My Private Pod:
`/Users/{MY_USER}/Repositories/Libs/{PRIVATE_POD_LIB}`

Crashlytics location within Private Pod:
`/Users/{MY_USER}/Repositories/Libs/{PRIVATE_POD_LIB}/Carthage/Build/iOS/Crashlytics.framework`

The app that pulls in my private pod:
`/Users/{MY_USER}/Repositories/Apps/{MY_APP}`

If I edit the crashlytics_path in Fastlane to this it works:
crashlytics_path: 
    `"/Users/{MY_USER}/Repositories/Libs/{PRIVATE_POD_LIB}/Carthage/Build/iOS/Crashlytics.framework",`

But obviously I don't want to put the full path with my user in it as it needs to work on a Jenkins server and other user machines.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to hardcode a path to work in multiple environments I would suggest using an environment variable.

For your local development machine environment, you could create a `.env` in your `fastlane` directory (`fastlane/.env`) with the following contents:

```
CRASHLYTICS_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/{MY_USER}/Repositories/Libs/{PRIVATE_POD_LIB}/Carthage/Build/iOS/Crashlytics.framework
```

Also make sure to add this `.env` file to your `.gitignore` file so that it does not get committed to your repository and does not get used on your Jenkins build.

You can then set the `CRASHLYTICS_FRAMEWORK_PATH` environment variable to something different on your Jenkins machine.

You can also find more documentation on environment variables here - https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/other/#environment-variables

Comment: That seems like a half-way solution, thanks! But it would mean that anyone checking out the repo would need to know to create the .env with this path in it. Is there a way to have a run script manually create this file, or if it exists, add the path to it?

Comment: So the .env works with:

CRASHLYTICS_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/{MY_USER}/Repositories/Libs/{PRIVATE_POD_LIB}/Carthage/Build/iOS/Crashlytics.framework

I tried to add to my podspec another build phase script like this:
{
    :name => 'Crashlytics Fastlane Env',
    :script => 'echo "CRASHLYTICS_FRAMEWORK_PATH=${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/Carthage/Build/iOS/Crashlytics.framework" > ../fastlane/.env',
    :execution_position => :after_compile
}

Which creates the .env file for me in my {MY_APP}/fastlane folder.

Comment: But the path it generates is:

CRASHLYTICS_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/{MY_USER}/Repositories/Apps/{MY_APP}/Pods/../../../Libs/{PRIVATE_POD_LIB}/Carthage/Build/iOS/Crashlytics.framework

But fastlane doesn't like it, I suspect it's the /../../../ it doesn't like.